# Why are all my nodes pointing to the same character array?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, pointers

wondering if I could get help with this singly linked list problem.

So I have a simple struct with a next pointer and char pointer to form each node.

```
struct node{
          char * nodeName;
          node * next;
           }
```

in my main function, I create a dynamically allocated array of chars called  name, which will be sent to a function that creates a new node each time it is called, a new name is supposed to be entered by the user each time and is supposed to be assigned to each new node created, but for some reasons ALL the nodes take the final name inputted.

My guess is that all the nodes are all pointing to the same char array, but I don't know how to fix this. Here is my code.

```
int main()
{

      char * name = new char[MAX_SIZE]; // dynamic array declaration;
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) // do it x number of times.
      {
           cout << "Enter Node Name" << endl;
           cin.get(name, MAX_SIZE, '\n');
           cin.ignore(200, '\n');
           addNode(name);
      }

 return 0
}


void addNode(name[])
{
if(!head){ // creates a first node,
         head = new node;
         head->next = NULL;
         head->nodeName = "default node";
}
    node * current = head;
    node * newNode = new node;
    newNode->name = name;//assign user inputed name.
    newNode->next = NULL // set next pointer to null
    while(current->next)
     current = current->next; // traverse to the last node;
     current->next = newNode; // connect the new node at the end.

}
```

The code does create the list, but the names of all the nodes are same, the very last char array inputted by the user.
Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to make a copy of name in addNode. Simplest is to make nodeName a std::string

Comment: Alternatively, move `char * name = new char[MAX_SIZE]` *inside* your loop. Honestly, though, using `std::string` is indeed the correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

All your nodes are pointing to the same character array because you only ever allocate one character array. So what else could they point to?

Since every call to `addNode` is passed the same pointer, when you do this:

```
newNode->name = name;//assign user inputed name.
```

You set every node's `name` member to the same value. That's not what you want to do.

What you do want to do depends on code you haven't shown us. Probably you want to allocate some memory in `addNode`, copy the supplied name into it, and set `newNode->name` to that pointer. You'll have to modify your code to release the node to deallocate that memory when you're done with it.

Alternatively, you could transfer ownership in `addNode`. But then you should change `main` to call `new` each time to allocate a new `name` object.

Comment: Thank you very much. This completely resolved the issue.